# Apache2: CSS not loading when the file is in another folder

Tags: html, css, apache2

**The problem is that my CSS is not loading.**

I have a folder /var/www/example, and in it i have my index.php 
and another folder assets where i have the folder /css

in my index.php i linked the css like this :

```
<link type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But when i put **style.css** in **/var/www/example** with **index.php** and i change my code to 
`href="style.css` it works !!

im working with **Apache2**

Comment: You are using a root relative path to the CSS file and presumably `/example` is a root folder so you would need `/example/assets/css/style.css` or you can try `href="assets/css/style.css"` if you want to link the CSS file relative to the location of the index page

Comment: @MonkeyZeus i tried this, i still have the same problem

Comment: What is the URL to your `index.php` file? Is it `http://localhost/example/index.php`?

Comment: Also, what is the full path to your CSS file?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus when i enter http://localhost/example/index.php i have page not found, but when i enter localhost/ i have my index.php

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  it's : /var/www/example/assets/css

Comment: What error do you get in your browser's Network console?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus when i enter localhost/example/index.php i have: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: @MonkeyZeus and when i enter localhost/  my index.php is loaded but without the css

Comment: What you visit localhost, what error does your network console tell you about the CSS file?

Comment: i don't have any errors there's just no css loading

Comment: i thought maybe it's something with apache2 server block but i dont know

Answer (score -1):

The root directory is `example` so you have to put `/example`  before `assets`  the link should be like the example below, Another idea is to remove the `/` before `assets` as it is not the `root directory` (i.e it is directory) of the `index.php` file.

```html
 <link type="text/css" href="/example/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Read the comments, `/example` is not used when accessing `index.php`